# Data synchronization from an android content provider to my remote server

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

I'm developing an app (Android 4.0) which relies on a background service to sync specific data from probably sqlite to a remote mysql database.

I am pretty new to Android dev (but not programming) and hence am still struggling with where to begin and how to construct the system. I am planning on leveraging:

["Developing Android REST client applications" by Virgil Dobjanschi (2010)](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)

as a starting point. What he demonstrates is a high level approach to developing such a system which is excellent.

My question is, in two years or so has anything changed, or would this still be considered a viable approach? Any other help you can give having gleened my situation will help me immensely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331388/android-do-application-login-in-background-on-boot-up/10476810#10476810) is an updated approach that I have found very useful

Use an Intent Service to get off the main thread for your requests.  If you want more info about services refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331388/android-do-application-login-in-background-on-boot-up/10476810#10476810).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Instead of services could the system just be run off events. I noticed that services running all the time and can drain the battery? Using broadcasts/recievers could be an approach...

Comment: A service is long running, and intent service is not.  an intent service will execute the code then die.  you could also just thread off the request.  the intent service with a result receiver just makes a clean reusable way for a callback response to be triggered.

Comment: Thanks again. Sounds like i could use an alarm broadcast to start my intent service, do some syncing and close it down (maybe).

Comment: Yes you could do that for auto refreshes. The first restful request can also be triggered by an event either by the application or by android (like onResume() or some other listener)