# Multiple instances of an app

Tags: android

I have android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the main activity in my manifest file. I think I am still getting multiple instances of the app under some circumstances. How can I tell?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578280/seems-like-my-little-android-app-is-running-multiple-instance) might be a helpful link.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Instead of

```
 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: Thanks for that Kat-hat. However, I would still like to know how to detect multiple instances .

Comment: Go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html.this may help you