# Android service when device restarted not working

Tags: android

Is any way that when device be turned off and turned on again
our android service be active again without activity
(Does not have to call an activity)?

Comment: I think you have to create  Broadcast Receiver and need to check device shutdown and startup receiver, at that time you can do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Comment: Many SO are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690350/android-start-service-on-boot