# How to keep my requestlocationupdates alive

Tags: java, android, locationlistener

I'm sending my coordinates to my server every 10meters so i can track myself.

`locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, meters, locationListener);`

this works fine i get my coordinates.
However i'm worried that after a while the phone will shutdown the app and my locationListener will stop?
Is there a way to ensure that my app will keep listening for locationupdates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Service` to keep track of your locationchanges, and in `onStartCommand` you can return `START_STICKY` to keep the `Service` alive until you stop it.

Example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: this seems to be the way to do it thanks. will look more into later tonight