# Android - Starting service by booting and wifi on

Tags: java, android

I am sorry for my bad english, I am from germany.
I try to explain my problem.

I'll start a service, if the smartphone booted and is internet connection enabled. I hope you can understand me.

This is my Autostart

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {
            try {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, SpyService.class));
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.caglar.spyme"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <receiver android:name=".Autostart" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".StartService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".SpyService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If i restart my phone and open the wlan, the service is not started. Why?

Comment: You have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time).

Comment: I tryed the same, but it isn't work

Comment: Have you tried instead to watch for connectivity changes, instead of battery or boot listener? If your receiver fires for a connectivity change, you can start your service when the WiFi is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code in your broadcast.

```
   public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

           ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
           context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
           NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
           boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();   
           if (isConnected)       
              // start your service
           }
    }
```