# IntentService not starting onBoot

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, intentservice, android-intentservice

I'm developing an app that synchronize your local date with the cloud. So I need to check automatically when the O.S. starts my local data to get the new camera files to upload to the cloud. And to do each 10 minutes a local data checking to get new files inside and uploading them to the cloud.

I'm having a trouble with the Service, because it starts only when I open the app, later I can close this app and it keeps in background (well!).But I need that the service starts when the operative system starts too.

I have defined in my Manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<service android:name=".receiver.UploadDeleteService"   android:exported="false"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"   android:process=":remote"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also I use an Interactor (from MVP architecture) where I define the alarm manager and the period of time:

```
public class ServiceInteractorImpl implements ServiceInteractor {

private Context context;

public ServiceInteractorImpl(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void launchService() {

    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent =  new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
    // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
            60*1000, pIntent);

}
```

}

My AlarmReceiver is:

```
public class AlarmReceiver  extends   BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, UploadDeleteService.class);
         context.startService(i);
    }
```

}

And my Service:

```
public class UploadDeleteService extends IntentService implements ApiConnector.GetObjectListener{

private RemoteInteractor remoteInteractor;
private LocalInteractor localInteractor;
private LocalDBInteractor localDBInteractor;
List<String> pathsToUpload;
private String uploading;

public UploadDeleteService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public UploadDeleteService() {
    super("UpdateDeleteService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    localInteractor = new LocalInteractorImpl(getApplicationContext());
    localDBInteractor = new LocalDBInteractorImpl(getApplicationContext());
    remoteInteractor = new RemoteInteractorImpl(getApplicationContext());
    uploading = "";
    remoteInteractor.checkNews(this);
}
```

}

Hope it helps to understand my trouble...Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try debugging by putting some log statements in onHandleIntent??

Comment: Yes, it shows messages only in onReceive inside AlarmReceiver, but it doesn't show any massage from onHandleIntent inside UploadDeleteService

Comment: try removing `android:process=":remote"` unless you have an explicit reason why it needs to run in its own process.

Comment: and do look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time. the third post says use wakefulservice

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, first of all thank you for all your answers. I took a mix and got a solution:

In my receiver, I added in my WakefulBroadcastReceiver the next lines to set the AlarmManger when the mobile phone booted again:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent!=null &&  intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Intent i =  new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

            final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
                    i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
            alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
                    30 * 1000, pIntent); 
        }else{ 
            Intent i = new Intent(context, UploadDeleteService.class);
            context.startService(i);
            startWakefulService(context, i);  

        }
    }
```

And I added in my Service:

@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

```
    remoteInteractor.checkNews(this);
    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);//Very important to link with your WakefulBroadcastReceiver
}
```