# Starting service on boot immediately java android

Tags: java, android, service

I use service in my app for lock statusbar.

This service is sticky and run on boot start

But my service start after 2-5 second and actived (on boot start).

Can i decrease this time?

Comment: You can't. System is managing processes.

Comment: there is no way. You don't control when your service will be started

Comment: @VladMatvienko There is many app that start quickly in boot.How this apps work?

Comment: why do you think that other apps start faster?

Comment: Maybe your service takes too long to initialize due to your code.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I think there is a way.But my service is empty,actually i create service without any code

Comment: It's a duplicated question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time

Comment: @omidaghakhani based on what you think that there is a way to do it? Logically, this couldn't be possible. Imagine the scenario: there is a priority value and you set it to the maximum for your app. Someone else create an app and he also set maximum priority. What should do the OS in that case?

Comment: @VladMatvienko This app install in 4 device that dont have any app(because this app is special)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, AndroidServiceStartOnBoot.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class AndroidServiceStartOnBoot extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       // here you can add whatever you want this service to do
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<receiver
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".AndroidServiceStartOnBoot"></service>
```

Comment: I knew it,i need run service quickly on boot android

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes,please attention i need run service quickly on boot

Comment: which part of the answer makes it start faster?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Really

Comment: use priority for broadcast receiver to start service immediately after boot complete.<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>