# Auto Start of service using BroadcastReceiver is not working?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, background-service

I want to auto start my service when device is rebooted.Please do not mark this as duplicate of [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time/30970167#30970167), but solution given there are not working!

**BootUpReceiver.java (BroadcastReceiver)**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.Map;


public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shubham.servic">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
    </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String msg = "Android : ";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
    }

    public void startService(View view) {
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }

    // Method to stop the service
    public void stopService(View view) {
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
    }
}
```

But still service is not starting itself on reboot.

*I have one more different question*:
I have to run my background service in fixed interval of time, So far I have created an `AlarmManager` inside service itself which is calling same service after some interval, again and again ,How can I achieve "running background service at fixed interval of time in more efficient way?"

Answer (score 1):

Because of restrictions in Android Oreo you can't start services while in the background. [source with detailed info](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Like the source suggests you should use scheduled jobs instead. The easiest way to manage this is to use a library like [android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) or [workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). Android Job is a much used 3rd party library developed by Evernote, but they've announced support will end when Workmanager, which is still in alpha, has been in production for a while.