# starting background service while phone turn on with example code

Tags: android

I need an app which will run always in the background and apps will start while phone is turn on. Please help me with example code. 
I already tried several code but it run on background while pressing button after start the apps

Comment: Take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562734/android-starting-service-at-boot-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED` of the phone, then start the service.
Follow the following steps

**Step 1: create your service**

```
public class myService extends Service{
    public  myService(){}
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Create your boot receiver**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, RemindersService.class);
        context.startService(i);    
    }
}
```

**Step 3: add them to manifest inside application**

```
    <service
        android:name=".services.RemindersService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".services.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Step 4: add permission in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Thats it. Happy coding.
Please note that in android Oreo, you will want to start service as foreground

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(i);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Lucem. If you don't mind , can i get little bit details code ??

Comment: That's the complete code I use. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @AbeedMukid consider upvoting and marking it as the right answer